# Safely using a hard drive dock

Tags: hard-disk, dock

I just pick up an Ez-Dock HD dock 2535. It came with sparse instructions ( and as usual Windows centric ). Software wise ie mounting, syncing,unmounting is not a problem.

Hardware wise though I am uncertain of what order I can do things and be safe.
This particular dock comes with a USB port ( eSata too but I won't be using it ), 
power supply, power button, sata power and data. Oh and a "one touch backup" button.

So under what circumstances can I use this without causing damage?
For example can I place a drive in the dock while power is on and the USB is connected? What removing a drive. Is it OK to power this thing off while the USB is connnected?

I would appreciate it if people described all possible circumstances.

Comment: Did any Linux drivers come with the dock? What OS are you running?

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](http://kingwin.com/products/cate/docking_stations/manual/EZ-dock_manual.pdf) your enclosure supports hot swap, which means you can plug in and unplug drives when there is power running through them. You should unmount the drive before removing it.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to remove a hot-swappable device on Linux is to run `echo 1 > /sys/block/device-name/device/delete` after unmounting and before physically removing the device. `dmesg` should then show the device as removed.

Adding a drive should be safe. You might need to rescan to find the drive with `echo "- - -" > /sys/class/scsi_host/host0/scan` if it is not picked up automatically (This assumes that the SCSI system manages the device)

`device-name` can be found, among other methods, by looking at the output of `ls -l /dev/disk/by-*`.

The desktop environment's option to safely remove the drive should also delete the device before informing you that it is safe to remove (in case you prefer a graphical way).